# javax.mail over Office365 read and ComparisonTerm issues

Tags: java, email, office365, jakarta-mail

I am simple trying to read all messages in inbox, then categorised to read, unread and greater or equal date terms. Please see my codes below. Username and password section passed.

Normally code is very simple, but I do not understand why I just get all emails.

Meanwhile, I am sure read messages. Also email received dates are different and we have new emails.

No exception or error I have.

Also checked below and couple of more questions.

[Read Recent and Unseen message using javax.mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017834/read-recent-and-unseen-message-using-javax-mail)

---

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.host", "outlook.office365.com");
    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3s");
    props.put("mail.pop3s.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new avax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, passwd);
        }
    });

    Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
    //Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");

    Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");
    store.connect();
    Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    myCal.setTime(new Date());
    myCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

    // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
    Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
    System.out.println("ALL : " + messages.length);

    messages =  emailFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
    //messages =  emailFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));    // not working also
    System.out.println("UNREAD : " + messages.length);

    messages =  emailFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true));
    //messages =  emailFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), true));     // not working also

    System.out.println("READ : " + messages.length);

    messages =  emailFolder.search(new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GE, myCal.getTime()));
    System.out.println("ReceivedDateTerm : " + messages.length);
```

Result is;
ALL : 18
UNREAD : 18
READ : 0
ReceivedDateTerm : 0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.pop3 package](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html), the POP3 protocol supports no permanent flags, so there's no way to tell if a message is RECENT or SEEN.  Use imap instead.

Also, you'll want to fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: Thanks Bill. Solved as how you advise.